# Parcheesi dice roll of double when all pawns still in nest

Tags: parcheesi

We are in debate as to the roll of a double on the dice rule when the player throwing the dice has all of the pawns still in the nest.  Since this does not appear to be 100% clear in the rules, it is being debated that regardless if all pawns are in the nest or not, that if a double roll is thrown, then that player is allowed to throw the dice again.  The contention is that if all pawns are in the nest, then that player has no pawn in the field of play and should not be allowed to roll again.  We have searched for a ruling on this and have not found any clear answer.  Please give some clear ruling on this!

Answer (score 1):

Depends on which rules you're using.

If you're playing with these [Parker Brothers rules](http://www.hasbro.com/common/instruct/parcheesi.pdf), you only get another turn if you used all of the double roll. If you can't use all of the roll, you don't get an extra turn.

> ### Doubles
>
> If a player throws doubles he has another turn and continues to have another turn as long as he throws doubles, *excepting* that if *he cannot complete the total move* on the dice he does *not* have another throw.

(emphasis original)

If you're playing with these [Milton Bradley rules](https://www.hasbro.com/common/instruct/Parcheesi_%282001%29.pdf), you get another throw regardless, unless it is your third doubles in a row.

> ### Doublets
>
> A roll of matching dice is called doublets. [...]
>
> - If you roll doublets before all of your pawns are entered, take your turn as usual, and then roll again.
> - Doublets Bonus: If you roll doublets after all four of your pawns are entered, use the four numbers on the tops and bottoms of the dice for movement. [...] If you can't take all four parts of your move, don't move your pawns at all. Whether you move or not, roll again.
> - Doublets Penalty: The third consecutive time you roll doublets, you may not move forward. Instead, your pawn closest to HOME (even if it's on your home path) must be returned to your START circle and re-entered later. This ends your turn.